# How to filter dates from multiple data sources in Tableau?

Tags: date, filtering, tableau-api

I have a Tableau workbook with two data sources. One data source is vehicle travel time delays and the other is for highway lane closures. The one for travel time delays has one date column for the specific date of measurement. The lane closure one has two date columns for the state and end of the closure.

I have made a calendar heatmap using the vehicle travel time delay data.

The lane closure data is in the form of columns that display the relevant information about the closures.

Is it possible to, when specifying a date through clicking on the date on the heatmap or in some way specifying a date,  filter the lane closure data to show only the lane closure information if the travel time date falls within the lane closure start and end?

Comment: Are these datasources joined/blended at all?

Comment: No, they were imported as separate datasources

Comment: I worry that this will not be possible using purely dashboard actions - those actions merely send values across sheets - as opposed to any sort of logic. You will probably have to experiment with blending/joining in order to create a table which has a value (true/false probably) that can be passed between sheets on your dashboard. Not positive though.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the response! I will do experimenting with that.